# Sending multiple files with from server to client with Javascript express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a folder on my server with multiple images, and I want to send all of them to the client-side and display them in the browser.

I've been trying few different things, but I cannot seem to make it work, since you're only allowed to send one response per request, and I can only send one file with `sendFile`

Basically, I want to take the images from the folder and send them all to client side and display them in the browser.

Here's an example of my server-side code:

```
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
 //using the node fs get all the files names from the folder
 const files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/images/"); 

 files.forEach(name => {
   //looping through the files and getting the specific path for each image
   const path = __dirname + "/images/" + name;     
 })

 //Here's the problem. I can only send one file with each response, using sendFile
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/images/" + "img.jpg" ); 
})
```

I've tried placing the `res.sendFile()` inside the for loop, but it gave me an error for trying send multiple responses at the same time. And I can only send one file with this.

Hope someone can help me understand this, and maybe suggest a method for how I can solve this.

Let me know if there's anything unclear about my code.

Comment: You can also check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615690/how-do-i-send-multiple-files-with-expressjs.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out and see if I can apply this to my code

Answer (score 1):

Create and send an HTML file with the list of images:

```js
res.send(htmlTemplate(files))
```

```js
function htmlTemplate(images) {
  return `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  ${images.map(name => `<img src="/images/${name}" />`).join('\n')}
</body>
</html>`
}
```

Also, make sure express can serve the individual images:

```js
app.use(express.static('images'))
```

---

On the other hand, for sending all the images in one response, you can encode the images in base64. This not recommended for large images because the transfer size would be more, and it can't make good use of caching.

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs').promises

app.get('files', async () => {
  const files = await fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, 'images'))
  const images = []
  for (const f of files)
    images.push(await fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'images', f), {encoding: 'base64'}))

res.send(`
<html>
<body>
  ${images.map(img => `<img src="data:image\/png;base64,${img}" />`)}
</body>
</html>
`)
});
```

Comment: So this means that I can just put these images into the html template and then send this html file to the client-side?

Comment: That can be done with encoding, but the above code is only including the image address. Therefore, the browser is going to ask the server for the actual images.

Comment: You mean in my code? cause I thought that I only needed the image path in order to send it with ```sendFile``` to the client-side. And this worked for me if I wanted to send only one image. But if I have a folder with multiple images, I didn't know how to do it

Comment: And using the ```app.use(express.static('images'))``` would help me with that? And if I want to send the ```htmlTemplate``` to the client-side, how do I deal with it there exactly? Just display it how it is?

Comment: My answer will send the client the addresses of the images. Then the client, will download them. It has to be one-by-one.

Comment: I don't necessarily want the client to download the images. I only want to use the get request in order to display all the images in the folder in the browser. But I can only send one image with ```sendFile``` and I can only send one response per request. Which is where I got stuck

Comment: Btw, thanks for the help! This actually cleared up some things to me